# Download a file with php and rename it

Tags: php, download

I have a `http://xrmrw.yt-downloader.org/download.php?id=b215e19671cd91d496f1568a7ca89d45&d=ME9x1mSNv-w, this link download a mp3 music.

I want in php to do smoething like that:

1- download the file on a specify location

2- rename it

I seriously don't know how to do that :(

Comment: That is also illegal, downloading via youtube, it violates youtube's TOS

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: 1- not duplicate